# Is it Possible to Pull Recipient Sent Information without Opening Email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I often times will need to open an email in a replying or forwarding view instead of looking at it in the folder view in order to pull the **From**, **Sent**, **To**, and **Subject**.

I wanted to know if there was a expedited way to pull this information without having to hit reply or forward.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to reply or forward, but you do need to open the email. That is where your required information is and where the headers are.

If Outlook, and If IMAP or POP, the OST or PST files are proprietary and not readily read without professional tools.

If Exchange, as your Exchange Admin, but again the format is proprietary.

If not Outlook, the same principles apply.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the subject of the message and the sender without opening the message.
But when you open the email, you can copy it directly. The subject appears at the very top of the message. You can right-click to copy the sender's address. This is shown in the figure below.
[image]

Alternatively, you can follow the method of Faery Fu-MSFT in this thread to set the view settings you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1345632/show-subject-above-the-sender-in-outlook-365

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.